# Swagger is not generating a full api documentation

Tags: java, swagger, jax-rs, openapi

I have configured my java application with jaxrs to generate the documentation for OpenAPI using [swagger-api](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core) but it's not generating all the fields of OpenAPI object.
Just is generating the fiedls, openapi, paths and components:

```json
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "paths": {
    "/dummyCheck": {
      "post": {
        "operationId": "dummyCheck",
        "requestBody": {
          "content": {
            "application/json": {
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Dummy"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "responses": {
          "default": {
            "description": "default response",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "Dummy": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "numero": {
            "type": "number"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have followed [the instructions that appear in the documentation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Getting-started#your-own-configuration), but adding an openapi-configuration.json file int the classpath or in WEB-INF it's not giving the expected result.

I have this in my `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2-servlet-initializer-v2</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.7</version>
</dependency>
```

And the class that expose the services is like this

```java
@Path("")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class RSDummyCheck {
    
    @Path("/dummyCheck")
    @POST
    public Response dummyCheck(Dummy input) {
        Dummy resultado = input;
        return Response.ok(resultado, "application/json").build();
    }

}
```

The config that i'm using in `openapi-configuration.json` is:

```json
{
    "prettyPrint" : true,
    "cacheTTL": 0,
    "readAllResources": true,
    "openAPI": {
        "info": {
            "version": "1.0",
            "title": "Title",
            "description": "Here is the description",
            "contact": {
                "email": "support@incredibleservice.com"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have moved the file openapi-configuration.json to all location that the documentation say it could be (WEB-INF, in the classpath) and i have changed the name and the extension, but nothing works.
I have debugged the io.swagger.v3.jaxrs2.integration.servlet.SwaggerServletInitializer and it is not reading the file.

Why the generation is incomplete and is not taken the openapi-configuration file?

Comment: You are missing the [required fields](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.0.3#fixed-fields) in your example.  I suspect that is not the root cause of your issue, but your issue [isn't reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with the example you've provided.

Comment: The only fields that appear are the required. The info about the service it's not appearing.